# A inequality involving $L^p$ norm and $L^1$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Prove \begin{equation} \lVert f\rVert_p\leq \sup_{\lVert g\rVert_q =1}\lVert fg\rVert_1 , 
\end{equation}where \begin{equation} \dfrac {1} {p} +\dfrac {1} {q}=1.\end{equation}

Comment: Is this an exercise from some book? Citing the source, in that case, is always a good idea. Moreover, some context would surely help: what have you tried? where did you get stuck? (This is not only useful to anyone answering because it makes them able to write better answers, but also because it shows what you know, giving a little sample of your knowledge on the subject) Also, these are norms on what vector space, exactly? Precision also never hurts.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Maybe it is an exercise in some book, but that's also a fundamental fact about $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: @julien, I know. That is more or less irrelevant: we prefer questions with context, which are not stated in the imperative, which show at least some work on the part of the OPs, and so on... This has been discussed to death already.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Right, I am aware of all these dicussions on no effort questions. And the imperative tone is not very nice. But I commented because I have to disagree: from the title and the question, the context, the norm, and the vector spaces are fairly clear.

Answer (score 3):

When $1\leq p< \infty$, Hölder gives the reverse inequality. Which is therefore an equality, where the sup turns out to be a a max. That's the isometric embedding of $L^p$ into $(L^q)^*$. It is always surjective when $1<p<\infty$. For $p=\infty$, if the measure is $\sigma$-finite, this still yields an isometry between $L^\infty$ and $(L^1)^*$.

So to get that inequality (assuming of course $\|f\|_p>0$), you need to take the right $g$. Try something based on $f$.

> For $p=1$, just take $g=1$. For $1< p<\infty$, take $$g=\frac{f^{p-1}}{\|f\|_p^{p-1}}.$$ For $p=\infty$, take a measurable set $A$ of positive measure on which $|f(x)|\geq (1-\epsilon) \|f\|_\infty$. Then set $$g=\frac{1_A}{\mu(A)}$$ to get that the rhs is $\geq (1-\epsilon) \|f\|_\infty$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: My teacher raise the problem in the final eaxm that maybe from some book.julien,thank you for your answer and commentary.Your answer and commentary are completely right.